# How to dont display IDs with google-visualization-errors-%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to change css code ith jquery on all IDs where this IDs have a name:

```
google-visualization-errors-%
```

so % is some word more ... etc. `google-visualization-errors-all-1, google-visualization-errors-2`

So when some IDs have a first keyword: google-visualization-errors... to change css setting to display:none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^=` which selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Try:

```
$('*[id^="google-visualization-errors-"]').css("display","none");
```

or simplier

```
$('*[id^="google-visualization-errors-"]').hide();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3U3hB/)

Comment: mwah ... u have been faster than me and your answer is simple and clean :) +1